# mysqli_multi_query not returning any value

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mysqli

I fired the following query with the help of `mysqli_multi_query`. Which is executing properly but not returning any value. It returning blank. Whats wrong with the `mysqli_multi_query` or is there any alternative for this for firing multiple queries in codeigniter.

```
   $sql="LOCK TABLE xp_subunit WRITE; ";
    $sql .= "SELECT @myLeft := ".$_GET['lft'].", @myRight :=  ".$_GET['rgt'].", @myWidth :=  ".$_GET['lft']." - lft + 1
    FROM xp_subunit
    WHERE id =".$_GET['id']."; ";

    $sql .= "DELETE FROM xp_subunit WHERE lft BETWEEN @myLeft AND @myRight; ";

    $sql .= "UPDATE xp_subunit SET rgt = rgt - @myWidth WHERE rgt > @myRight; ";
    $sql .= "UPDATE xp_subunit SET lft = lft - @myWidth WHERE lft > @myRight; ";
    $sql.="UNLOCK TABLES;";

    //echo $sql;
    $query = $this->db->mysqli_multi_query($sql);
```

Comment: just a note: there is a potential sql injection vulnerability (passing in $_GET['id'], and so on, unescaped)

Comment: Please post the way you're reading the values.

Comment: See the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) examples, there's an example how to retrieve the results from a multi query.

Comment: Is there a `mysqli_multi_query` in Codeigniter? Don't you need to use the native PHP function?

Comment: @Yan mysqli can be used as database driver in CodeIgniter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Try with the following Example.,

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$query  = "SELECT CURRENT_USER();";
$query .= "SELECT Name FROM City ORDER BY ID LIMIT 20, 5";

/* execute multi query */
$mysqli->multi_query($query);
?>
```

I think this may help you to get the solution.